# How to check if a transaction went through?

Tags: transactions, horizon

When we submit a transaction to Horizon, we either get a success response or an error response. In the case of an error response, we can save the transaction in XDR format and resend it.

**But, if we get a success response, is it safe to assume that the transaction will never fail?**

Also does success response mean the transaction in included in ledger? If not, how can we be sure that the transaction is added to ledger? Is there anything like checking transaction status using its hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, if we get a success response, is it safe to assume that the transaction will never fail?

Yes.

> Also does success response mean the transaction in included in ledger?

Yes.

**Horizon returns success result only when the tx makes it into the ledger**. Just wait for the response from Horizon and you will know for sure if your transaction was successful or not.

Comment: So this means in case of the heavy load on Stellab BC, it may take 5-10 mins to get the response from the Horizon? Isn't there anything like we send the tx and check if tx went through using tx hash later (maybe via a crone)?